# Increment index of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to find the element placed right after `$input` but it seems that the type of index is not int and because of that I can not do mathematical operations on it .

```
$index = array_search($input,$tmp);
$index += 1 ;
$hold = $tmp[$index];
echo $hold;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't over think it, just use `array_values()`:

```
$index = array_search($input, array_values($tmp));
$index += 1;
$hold  = array_values($tmp)[$index];
echo $hold;
```

You probably want to do some checking to make sure a key was returned from `array_search()` and check that the next index `isset()`.

```
$vals  = array_values($tmp);
$index = array_search($input, $vals);

if($index !== false && isset($vals[++$index])) {
    $hold = $vals[$index];  // it has already incremented with the ++$index
    echo $hold; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_search()` Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

So you beed to check that something was found before assuming it was.

Also as you are adding 1 to the index it would be a good idex to check that the found key is not the last occureance in the array.

```
$index = array_search($input,$tmp);
if ( $index !== false && $index < count($tmp) -2 ) {
    echo $tmp[$index + 1]; 
} else {
     echo 'Not found'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next() might need to set current() on search first